# Using General tab, unable to lock device orientation of the app for iPad

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, device-orientation

I am using Xcode 9.4. In the .xcodeproj file, under General tab, I have unchecked Portrait and Upside Down options. Still the app rotates to both of these modes. Please help me with the same

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

AppDelegate, if you rotate device, push viewController, etc. This function always call

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask
{
    return self.restrictRotation
}
```

for use:

in AppDelegate:

```
var restrictRotation:UIInterfaceOrientationMask = .portrait
```

& in the viewController When method ViewDidLoad or viewWillAppear is called. We will change like this:

```
(UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).restrictRotation = .all
```

and then this method on AppDelegate will be called.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask
```